# multiplying along with aggregating in sql

Tags: sql, hive

I was running the query below

```
SELECT
    a.num_week,
    CAST(COUNT(distinct a.account_id)*b.fraud_rate as BIGINT) as unpaid_other
FROM ads_weekly_total_unpaid_other a
JOIN ads_weekly_unpaid_other_fraud_rate b
ON a.num_week = b.num_week 
GROUP BY a.num_week
```

I got the error below Expression not in GROUP BY key 'fraud_rate'. I want to multiply the overall count per week by the fraud_rate but why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT z.num_week,CAST(countId * y.fraud_rate)  as unpaid_other
FROM (

      SELECT a.num_week,COUNT(distinct a.account_id) as countId
      FROM ads_weekly_total_unpaid_other a
      JOIN ads_weekly_unpaid_other_fraud_rate b
      ON a.num_week = b.num_week 
      GROUP BY a.num_week
    )z

JOIN ads_weekly_unpaid_other_fraud_rate y
ON y.num_week=z.num_week
```

Comment: So we cannot do it inside?

Comment: as far as i know it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are grouping only on `a.num_week`, you are using the aggregate function `COUNT(Distinct` on `a.account_id` but you do not have any aggregate function on `b.fraud_rate`, neither it is in the group by Key, hence the error. Since  `fraud_rate` is constant across account_id for one instance of `num_week`, you can use any aggregate function like `min`, `max`, `avg` on `b.fraud_rate` and it will be giving you same result.

```
SELECT a.num_week,
CAST((COUNT(distinct a.account_id)* MAX(b.fraud_rate)) as BIGINT) as unpaid_other
FROM ads_weekly_total_unpaid_other a
JOIN ads_weekly_unpaid_other_fraud_rate b
ON a.num_week = b.num_week 
GROUP BY a.num_week;
```

I did not get a change to execute the query here. But I am guessing it should work.